# Trying to count total from Rails query

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I'm new to Rails and I've been trying to do ActiveRecord query, but simply can't seem to find how to phrase it.

Here's the SQL equivalent of what I'm trying to do

```
SELECT c.name, COUNT(p.*) FROM Categories AS c
JOIN products AS p ON c.id = p.category_id
GROUP BY c.name, c.id
```

I tried variations of

```
Product.select(:category).group(:category).count
```

and

```
Category.joins(:products).group(:category_id).count
```

But haven't found the right syntax, yet.

Is it possible to do? The project is based on Rails 4.2.